# Is Node Mongodb Native Driver v 2.2 still compatible with node 0.12.X?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use the [Mongodb Native Driver For Node](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) v2.1 with a node app in 0.12.X version.
I've just upgrade the driver to the 2.2 version, but I get this error with a simple insert:

```
/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:320
  self.s.pool = new Pool(Object.assign(self.s.options, options, {bson: this.s.
                                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Server.connect (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:320:33)
    at Server.connect (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:328:17)
    at open (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:220:19)
    at Db.open (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:243:44)
    at connectFunction (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:220:67)
    at connect (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:367:5)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:113:3)
    at PriceInsert._write (/web-apps/j2ee/jenkins/back/src/helpers/price-insert-stream.js:34:21)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
```

The [documentation for driver compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-language-node) is not to date, as there is only the requirements for the 2.1 version. They seems to use ES2015 features (Object.assign) that is not compatible with node 0.12.X.

Do I have to stay in v 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found an issue on their Jira tracker, this bug will be fixed in the next release, the 2.2.1.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-747?jql=project%20%3D%20NODE